# Removing hovered item from array with filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add an `.inactive` class to every element in an array excluding the element that has the `mouseover` event being triggered. I would like to do this with the `filter` function, however, I'm not sure how to 'filter' the hovered `.item` from the array of `items`. Currently, all `items` are getting the `.inactive` class added to them

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

[...items].forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        console.log(link)
        const inactives = [...items].filter(item => link)
        inactives.forEach(inactive => {
            inactive.classList.add('inactive')
        });
    });
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        [...items].forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('inactive')
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.item.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify your filter by comparing to the current link:

```
const inactives = [...items].filter(item => item !== link)
```

I would also add the `inactive` class to all links to begin.

To simplify, you could simply add the `inactive` class to all items on `mouseout` and remove it on your hovered item on `mouseover`. That way, you don't need to filter the links.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

[...items].forEach(link => {
    link.classList.add('inactive');

    link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        link.classList.remove('inactive');
    });

    link.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        [...items].forEach(item => {
            item.classList.add('inactive');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.item.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is mostly right. with some small changes it will work.

ready the comment.

Here is an example.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
[...items].forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        const inactives = [...items].filter((item) =>  item != link) // return all items except the current item
        
        link.classList.remove('inactive') // remove inactive from the current item
        inactives.forEach(inactive => {
            inactive.classList.add('inactive')
        });
    });
    
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        [items].forEach(item => {
         if (item.classList)
            item.classList.remove('inactive')
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.item.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
```